# Flutter Firestore retrieve and set nested object

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i have this document structure in firestore.

[image]

i want to create supplier quotation object with this data but i can't map product data into product object  how can i do it??

```
class SupplierQuotation {
  String details;
  Supplier supplier;
  Product product;
  Requisition requisition;

  SupplierQuotation(
      this.details, this.product, this.requisition, this.supplier);

  SupplierQuotation.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : details = firestore['details'],
        //supplier.suplierName = firestore['supplier'],
        product = firestore['product'];
  // requisition = firestore['requisition'];
}
```

firestore service code

```
Stream<List<SupplierQuotation>> getSupplierQuatations() {
    var object = _db
        .collection('supplierQuotation')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents
            .map(
              (document) => SupplierQuotation.fromFirestore(document.data),
            )
            .toList());

    return object;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to manually create objects and map properties to make this work.
now its working fine.

```
 class SupplierQuotation {
  String details;
  Supplier supplier;
  Product product;
  Requisition requisition;

  SupplierQuotation(
      this.details, this.product, this.requisition, this.supplier);

  SupplierQuotation.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : details = firestore['details'],
        supplier = Supplier(
            supplierName: firestore['supplier']['supplierName'].toString()),
        product = Product(
          desc: firestore['product']['desc'].toString(),
          price: double.parse(firestore['product']['price'].toString()),
        ),
        requisition = Requisition(
          reqNo: firestore['requisition']['reqNo'].toString(),
        );
}
```

Comment: can you please structure of your firestore collection?

Answer (score 1):

i added to each nested object toJson() / fromJson() in the parent object's toJson() / fromJson()